# not autocomplete local file when call in Visual Code

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, filepath

when in visual code call file not autocomplete 
example this code  :

```
@extends('layout.layout')
```

when write "layout" not autocomplete

excuse me, I cant speak English well

Comment: What extensions are you using for Laravel development? I don't think VSCode supports Blade Syntax completions without having the correct extensions installed.

Comment: I installed extension "Laravel Blade Snippets" but not autocomplete file path

Answer (score 1):

"Laravel Blade Snippets" provides shortcuts for writing Blade code in Laravel views, so there's no intellisense for it to read through your views folder.[Here's an extension](https://github.com/amir9480/vscode-laravel-extra-intellisense) that *claims* to provide autocomplete for view files, I tried to fiddle around with it myself and couldn't get it to work though. I'll also add, that my experience with extensions that add file path completions can really slow down VSCode.

I think if you're looking for more robust features like intellisense/auto completion for a framework like Laravel, you should check out PHPStorm. It requires a paid subscription after a 30 day trial but is a great IDE for Laravel, be careful though because it will spoil you if you decide to stop paying for it and go back to VSCode for Laravel development!

One more note, during my rather quick research for VSCode Laravel extensions, I saw a few people mention Sublime Text has some good plugins for Laravel development. So there's another option for you to check out, good luck!